# OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_n', 'unexpected eof while reading')] when updating / searching / installing conda packages

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I try to perform any operation that requires connecting to any conda channels, e.g. `update --all`,
I get the following error, always in the first step:

```
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_n', 'unexpected eof while reading')]
```

The workaround is uninstalling and then installing the entire Anaconda distribution.
After that any conda command works as expected for the rest of the day.
BUT the next day I start getting the above error again.
I know it's not due to any networking restriction because I can load all the channel URLs in the browser (and because re-installation fixes the problem temporarily).

Right now the software versions are:

- conda version : 4.8.3
- conda-build version : 3.18.11
- python version : 3.7.7.final.0

Does anyone else have the same issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be related to openssl 1.1.1e bug
Check version that you have

```
yum info ea-openssl11
```

If you have 1.1.1e, then you can downgrade to 1.1.1d

```
yum downgrade ea-openssl11
```

Comment: Alexey, you were right. Thank you. I re-installed Anaconda and upgraded openssl to 1.1.1f once it was available, and the problem was gone. And my other machine without the issue had 1.1.1f on it already. So it definitely appears that it was caused by a bug in 1.1.1e.